# Why special characters don't get interpreted in DOM when inserted with JS?

Tags: javascript, special-characters, htmlspecialchars

I load a script after page had loaded (not immediately, just when user calls it from bookmarklet). This script will check the current page and change some text from the current value to the value the script specifies.

To be more specific, this is used in translation. For example it changes "Friends" to "Freunden" in another language and so on.

I do this by using a "switch" statement to pick from the chosen language. Problem is, I have exotic languages like Arabic for example, and the statement looks like this (pseudo-code) :

`if (Arabic) { var f = '&#1044;&#1088;&#1091;&#1079;&#1100;&#1103;'}`

Then, this variable is used to change the inner text of a specified node in the DOM, like so :

`dI('change').childNodes[0].childNodes[0].textContent = f;`

The text will appear untouched in DOM with all entities not interpreted, NOT the way it should in their resulting language. How do I make the browser interpret the entities while passing them like above ??

Comment: You have to set the content as HTML, not as text: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML.

Answer (score 3):

Use `innerHTML` instead of `textContent`, like that in your case:

```
dI('change').childNodes[0].childNodes[0].textContent = f;
```

Becomes:

```
dI('change').childNodes[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML = f;
```

Comment: Yup, worked. Thanks a lot. This was one of those dork "ahaa" moments, when I don't know the easy ones. Much respect 2 you sir.